# Swift and Objective C files in CocoaPods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, mapbox

I have the below Podfile.

```
 target '*****' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for *****
  # pod 'Netcore-Smartech-iOS-SDK'

pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
pod 'AMSlideMenu', '~> 1.5.4'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'MZFormSheetController'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'LTHMonthYearPickerView'



  target '****CabsTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target '***CabsUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
  #pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
end
```

Its working fine ,

But when I start importing the below , it give me error:
"
Showing Recent Messages
: Library not found for -lAFNetworking

: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.6.0'  

    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
    pod 'AMSlideMenu', '~> 1.5.4'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'MZFormSheetController'
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'LTHMonthYearPickerView'
```

Please suggest what make me wrong.

Comment: Just `import AFNetworking.h` not work?

Comment: [Check GitHub issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/issues/253).

Comment: @Tj3n not working dear

Answer (score 0):

The linker flag has been renamed to:

-lAFNetworking
but the Cocoapods settings have not been updated yet. Rename the entry in "Other Linker Flags" and your problem will be solved.

Also, the library does not support Bitcode yet, thus please turn off Bitcode in Build Options > Enable Bitcode > Select "No". Clean & Rebuild afterwards.

Comment: Bitcode is already set to "NO".
Not getting what to do on "Other linker flag".. PLease let me know with proper rename. what I have to rename

Comment: Target -> Build Setting -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags...


In the the Other Linker Flags section, remove -l"Pods-AFNetworking" and replace it with -l"AFNetworking"

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'.

Like this:

```
use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'ProjectName' do

    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
  # Pods for ProjectName

end
```